# Getting pk from selected object in a generic ListView html to populate a FK for a new form (CBV)

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I'm trying to make a carwash app and I am having issues getting the wash form populated with the vehicle's pk. I've tried with "get_initial", "get_context_data", "form_valid", **passing {% url   'appname:urlname' object.pk %} in a html button**, even thought about formsets. So if you can guide this noob in polishment (me), I would greeeeaaaatly apreciate it!

so this is what the code is simplified to...

model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
   carplates = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

class Wash(models.Model):
   vehicle_to_wash = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   specific_comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True
```

form:

```
class WashServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Wash
        fields = ['specific_comment', 'vehicle_to_wash']
```

views:

```
class CarList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Car

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Car.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CarList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['car_list'] = context['object_list'].filter(user=self.request.user)
        return context

class WashService(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Wash
    form_class = WashServiceForm
    template_name = 'service_app/standard_wash_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('service_app:wash_review')

class WashReview(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Wash
```

urls:

```
app_name = 'service_app'

urlpatterns = [

    path('car-list/', CarList.as_view(), name='car_list'),
    path('<int:id>/select_wash/', WashService.as_view(), name='wash_service'),
    path('<int:pk>/review', WashReview.as_view(), name='wash_review'),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

For class based views you can use `self.kwargs.get('parameter')`

You also need to add `get_success_url` to your `class WashService`

```
class WashService(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Wash
    form_class = WashServiceForm
    template_name = 'service_app/standard_wash_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('service_app:wash_review',args=[self.object.id])
```